# Excel 365 function/formula names gets translated. How to avoid it?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365

I am using excel 365 (web) within 3 computers (one with Win8.1, another with W10, and a tablet with W10 also), each with one language configuration (between English and Spanish, not in my hand to change, sorry)

Also, I open the workbooks with the App version on the Desktop

it occurs that in browsers, I need to type formulas in Spanish instead of English to work, (i.e. SUMA instead of SUM) even in the pick up list appear in English, even keyboard is set to English and nevermind if computer is set to Spanish or English

**How can avoid excel translating formulas at every single time?**

I have my profile all set up in English in oneDrive, and everything else happens to be in English. Only thing set up to Spain is my location (as I am located now indeed in Spain) but try to set everything else, even my Account-location on UK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel uses the system settings for its language choice, even "," , "." , ";" and ":" behave differently based on thr system settings.

Set or install all 3 computers to the same language from the start, just setting the keyboard layout is not sufficient.

Comment: ok
so the fomula names languaje (I also notice with the dot and semicolon interchange) get its configuration form the location settings for time and curreny??  [MS: whatTheHeck???]